# Launch image xCode archiving

Tags: ios

Am not using storyboard. And I've created a LaunchImage inside XCAssets with all the required sizing. After I click Product >>> Archive >>> Upload to App Store..., I get the following error message after a long wait.

"your binary is not optimized for iphone 5 - new iphone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iphone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}".

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you need help with? You don't provide any useful details about what you have done. Do you have a Launch Screen file (storyboard)? Do you have an launch images? What is your app's Base SDK and Deployment Target? Edit your question with all the relevant details.

Comment: @rmaddy. I have made some changes to the above question

Comment: The error states you don't have a launch image for the iPhone 5. So add one.

Comment: OMG... I've filled all the spaces there are in xcassets

Comment: Update your question with a screenshot of your launch images asset in Xcode. BTW - why aren't you using a launch screen file instead of launch images? It's much easier and is required to support the iPad Pro as well as multitasking on supported iPads.

Comment: Yes, its so much easier to use launch screen file. Fixed now